# Vba for Text string + another cell value + text string

Tags: string, excel, vba, text

I have a problem. I have simple excel table with pictures that changes number of row every day. I adapted vba code found on internet (I am very new to vba). I wanted to add a string at the first empty cell (last row of the table) and managed that using vba. But the string contains a number that changes every day and I need to update that numer along with the string. The number is number of non empty rows after filter applied and is contained in some cell in the same workbook. How can you make vba that would adapt to what I already have? So it goes like this:
1. Find first empty cell (donne)
2. Select a range from finded cell and merge (donne)
3. Add a text string + number from another cell (the cell contains formula to calculate that number) + another part of text string (this part is my problem)?

Best regard to anyone who can help

Comment: You need to post your existing code, or this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks for warning me I will put the code next time right away, my bad so no hard feelings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like the user has provided enough info and has explained how they arrived at their current roadblock (plus they are new), so I will give them the benefit of the doubt and provide my input.

Code:
[image: code]

Output

[image: output]

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Whatever cell you want this in").Value = textstring1 & ActiveSheet.Range("Cell with the formula/number you need").Value & textstring2
```

In the parentheses you would put the cell or range you want the value from for example:
 `ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value`

Also, instead of hard coding your text strings you can use variables. So, in place of `"Test"` you could use say variable `string1`, which you defined above your code and gave a value like so:

`Dim string1 as String: string1 = "Test"`

Comment: Thanks very much, this answer is very helpful to me and I now managed the problem. Quick and accurate answer and excellent problem understanding as I did not provide full info, but this is difference between human intelligence and a computer programm. Humans can read  between the lines!

Comment: Here is the code(I so new and my browser so old that formatting look very strange so I am not really sure where to post the code ):

Comment: Sub Macro1 ()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 For Each cell In ws.Columns(5).Cells
 If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
 Next cell
Dim string1 As String: string1 = "* Note: In this review are ... a total of"
Dim string2 As String: string2 = "in this day) is given in W drive, ""Something"""
ActiveCell.Value = string1 & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Value & " " & string2
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)).Select
        With Selection
        .WrapText = True
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
End Sub